# How should i put this middleware in my tornado project？

Tags: tornado, opentracing

I am using opentracing these days, and i see a middleware example. but i don't know how to add it to my tornado project.

code here:

```
class TracerMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # perform initialization similar to above, including installing
        # the client_hooks
        pass

    @gen.coroutine
    def __call__(self, request, handler, next_mw):
        request_wrapper = TornadoRequestWrapper(request=request)
        span = before_request(request=request_wrapper)

        @gen.coroutine
        def next_middleware_with_span():
            yield next_mw()

        yield run_coroutine_with_span(span=span, func=next_middleware_with_span)

        span.finish()


def run_coroutine_with_span(span, func, *args, **kwargs):
    """Wrap the execution of a Tornado coroutine func in a tracing span.

    This makes the span available through the get_current_span() function.

    :param span: The tracing span to expose.
    :param func: Co-routine to execute in the scope of tracing span.
    :param args: Positional args to func, if any.
    :param kwargs: Keyword args to func, if any.
    """
    with span_in_stack_context(span):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tornado doesn't have a concept of "middleware". This looks like it's designed to be used with a subclass of `Application` (Maybe [this one](https://pastebin.com/547sjA6f)?). Your best bet is to ask the authors of this "middleware" to provide better instructions ([see this issue](https://github.com/uber-common/opentracing-python-instrumentation/issues/43)).

Note that this implementation relies on `tornado.stack_context`, which no longer exists in Tornado 6. It needs to be [updated](https://github.com/uber-common/opentracing-python-instrumentation/issues/83) to use `contextvars` to support Tornado 6.